# Calculate the average of Spearman correlation

Tags: excel, matlab, average, correlation

I have 2 columns A and B which contain the Spearman's correlation values as follows:

```
 0.127272727    -0.260606061
-0.090909091    -0.224242424
0.345454545      0.745454545
0.478787879      0.660606061
-0.345454545    -0.333333333
0.151515152     -0.127272727
0.478787879     0.660606061
-0.321212121    -0.284848485
0.284848485     0.515151515
0.36969697     -0.139393939
-0.284848485    0.272727273
```

How can I calculate the average of those correlation values in these 2 columns in Excel or Matlab ? I found a close answer in this link : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values
The main point is we can not use mean or average in this case, as explained in the link. They proposed a nice way to do that, but I dont know how to implement it in Excel or Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

Following the **second** answer of the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values) you provided, which is the most general case, you can calculate the average Spearman's rho in Matlab as follows:

```
M = [0.127272727    -0.260606061;
    -0.090909091    -0.224242424;
    0.345454545      0.745454545;
    0.478787879      0.660606061;
    -0.345454545    -0.333333333;
    0.151515152     -0.127272727;
    0.478787879     0.660606061;
    -0.321212121    -0.284848485;
    0.284848485     0.515151515;
    0.36969697     -0.139393939;
    -0.284848485    0.272727273];


z = atanh(M);
meanRho = tanh(mean(z));
```

As you can see it gives mean values of

```
meanRho = 
0.1165    0.1796
```

whereas the simple mean is quite close:

```
mean(M)

ans =

0.1085    0.1350
```

Edit: more information on Fisher's transformation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation).

Answer (score -1):

In MATLAB, define a matrix with these values and use [mean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) function as follows:

```
%define a matrix M
M = [0.127272727    -0.260606061;
-0.090909091    -0.224242424;
0.345454545      0.745454545;
0.478787879      0.660606061;
-0.345454545    -0.333333333;
0.151515152     -0.127272727;
0.478787879     0.660606061;
-0.321212121    -0.284848485;
0.284848485     0.515151515;
0.36969697     -0.139393939;
-0.284848485    0.272727273];

%calculates the mean of each column
meanVals = mean(M);
```

Result

```
meanVals =
0.1085    0.1350
```

It is also possible to calculate the total meanm and the mean of each row as follows:

```
meanVals = mean(M); %total mean
meanVals = mean(M,2); %mean of each row
```